# Why getting this error non-numeric value encountered in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.1

I am trying to download pdf file in my Laravel 5.4 application using dompdf.
here is my controller code:

```
public function htmltopdfview($master_id) {
$ordermaster=DB::table('allorder')->where([['user_id',Auth::user()->id], 
                                          ['id',$master_id]])->first();
$orderdetails=DB::table('allorder_details')->where('master_id',$master_id)->get();
$pdf = PDF::loadView('OrderReport',compact('ordermaster','orderdetails'));
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
return view('OrderReport',compact('ordermaster','orderdetails'));
}
```

Here is my blade file code:

```
@foreach($orderdetails as $details)
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-9"><em>{{$details->product}}</em></td>
        <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center">{{$details->product_price}} TK </td>
        <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align: center">${{$details->product_price/80}}  </td>
        <td class="col-md-1 text-center">{{$details->barnd}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach

<div>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">
        Thank you for your order.
        <a href="{{route('pdfdownload',$ordermaster->id)}}">Download PDF</a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

Here is my route:

```
    Route::get('htmltopdfview/{id}','CheckoutController@htmltopdfview')->name('pdfdownload');
```

error screenshot :
[image: got this error non-numeric value encountered]

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case I recommend to make sure that your Dompdf is latest version. Block.php only has 287 lines in latest version and you error happens on line 741.

Otherwise your HTML is not valid and table rows have no table. Dompdf is very sensitive to any invalid HTML code.